# Find $a,b$ to make $V$ a Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Given $V(x,y)=ax^2+by^2$ I'm asked to find $a$ and $b$ to make $V$ a Lyapunov function for the following systems:

$(1)$\begin{cases} x'= -x^\color{red}{3}+xy^2 \\ y'= -\color{red}{2}x^2y-y^3\end{cases}

Here I have $\dot{V}(x,y)=2ax(-x^2+xy^2)+2b(-y^3)=2ax^3+2ax^2y-4bx^2y^2-2by^4$.

The first two termins can take positive and negative values depending on $x$, then here I would set $a=0$; then $b>0$ to make it $\dot{V}(x,y)\leq 0$.

$(2)$\begin{cases} x'= -x^\color{red}{3}/2+2xy^2 \\ y'= -y^3\end{cases}

In this case is $\dot{V}(x,y)=2ax(-x^2/2+2xy^2)+2b(-y³)=-ax^3-x^2y^2-2by^3$.

For the middle term is $-x^2y^2\leq 0$, but $-ax^3-2by^3$ could be less or greater than zero for any $a,b$ chossing an appropiate $x,y$. Then in this case $a=b=0$ is the only possible solution?

**UPDATE:** I copied the problem from my notes instead of the original problem, doing this I messed up some of the exponents. The fixed exponents are those in red, which I before miscopied as 2; I also missed a constant.

Comment: @Amzoti I took it from a set of problems given to me in college.
I can give you the full set if you want (is not in english)

Comment: @Amzoti I'm very sorry :(, now that I look at the sheet (instead of my notes) I see that I messed it up with one of the exponents :( 
Should I edit, or delete and open a new question? :(

Comment: @Amzoti There. I fixed the exponents and explained the change in the update section.

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, is $y'=y^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution for Updated Problem**

The phase portrait for the first problem is given by (single critical point at origin):

[image]

The phase portrait for the second problem is given by (single critical point at origin):

[image]

For:

$$V(x,y)=ax^2+by^2$$

The derivative is:

$$V'(x, y) =  2 a x x' + 2 b y y'$$

Now substitute in $x'$ and $y'$, simplify and choose $a$ and $b$ accordingly.

For (1), we have:

$$V'(x, y) = -2 a x^4 +x^2 y^2(2a-4b) -2by^4$$

We need to choose $a$ and $b$ such that:

$$V(x, y) > 0~\mbox{and}~V'(x, y) \lt 0 ~ \forall ~(x, y) \ne (0,0)$$

Do you see how to choose $a$, $b$ to satisfy this? For example, $a > 0, b > 0$ with $a = 2b$. That first choice eliminates the middle term. You could also choose $a > 0, b > 0, a \lt 2b$ (all terms negative).

For $(2)$, we have:

$$V'(x, y) = -a x^4 + 4 a x^2 y^2 - 2 b y^4$$

What do you need to show the second one? Recall, you **can not** choose $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, else you do not have a valid Lyapunov Function.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If $a=0$ $V(x,y)$ is not a Lyapunov function.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks! What did you use to do that plot?

Comment: @Amzoti I really do not get what you are trying to "prove" in the way you did in your Update.

Comment: The last one looks like a quadratic form, maybe it could be expressed in such form with a change $u=x^2,v=y^2$.
Is it valid to consider the form $-(au^2-4au^2v^2+2bv^2)$ and to show that $au^2-4au^2v^2+2bv^2$ is definite positive? Because this happens if $4ba+16a^2>0$, which can be done choosing $b>0,a>0$ or $b<0, a>b/4$. Does this show that $a,b$ to make $V'\leq 0$ exist?